# Retrieving contents of j2 template file on stdout

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm attempting to use Ansible to better manage my Kubernetes configmaps in a multienvironment project (dev, stage, and prod). I've generalized each of the config maps as j2 templates, and I'll override the variables depending on how they might change in different environments (so that they aren't duplicated three times for basically the same file).

My playbook currently looks something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ env }}.yml"
  tasks:
    - name: Generate YAML from j2 template
      template:
        src: templates/foo.j2
        dest: output/foo.yml
```

And this has been working great for testing so far. However, I'm at the point where I want to incorporate this into my already existing Jenkins CI/CD, but I'm having trouble understanding how it might work with what I am doing currently.

After generating what is basically a Kuberenets ConfigMap from the j2, I'll somehow do this within Jenkins:

```
kubectl apply -f <yaml>
```

However, the playbook is creating a YAML file every time I run it, and I am wondering if there is an alternative that would allow me to pipe the contents of the YAML file or somehow retrieve it from stdout.

Basically, I want to evaluate the template and retrieve it without necessarily creating a file.

If I do this, I could do something like the following:

```
echo result | kubectl apply -f -
```

where result of course is the contents of the YAML file that results after the templating, and the short dash after the f flag specifies Kubernetes to use the process' stdout.

Sorry for so much explaining, I can clarify anything if needed.

Comment: Hi Andys1814, welcome to SO. Your question is unclear -- the `-f` of `apply` expects a file, which you appear to be generating as `output/foo.yml`; where does stdin come into play? Can you show more of an example of what you want to be doing?

Comment: Ah sorry, I totally agree that my question is unclear. In kubectl you can do "kubectl apply -f -" where the short dash at the end directs Kubernetes to use the process' stdout. So, I would like to retrieve the result of the template, and pipe it into that command, such as "echo result | kubectl apply -f -" I also modified the OP if that is easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to retrieve the result of the template, and pipe it into that command, such as "echo result | kubectl apply -f -"

In which case, you'd use the `stdin:` parameter of the [`command:` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/command_module.html#parameters):

```yaml
- name: generate kubernetes yaml
  command: echo "run your command that generates yaml here"
  register: k8s_yaml

- name: feed the yaml to kubectl apply
  command: kubectl apply -f -
  stdin: '{{ k8s_yaml.stdout }}'
```

It isn't super clear what the relationship is in your question between the top part, dealing with the `template:`, and the bottom part about `apply -f -`, but if you mean "how can I render a template to a variable, instead of a file?" the the answer is the [`template` lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/lookup/template.html):

```yaml
- name: render the yaml
  set_fact:
    k8s_yaml: '{{ lookup("template", "templates/foo.j2") }}'

- name: now feed it to apply
  command: kubectl apply -f -
  stdin: '{{ k8s_yaml }}'
```

Comment: I am templating my ConfigMaps because they are basically the same file, with only very minor modifications for different environments. In some cases only the namespace changes (dev, stage, prod).  After I generate the configmap based on environment, I will apply it through kubectl. I hope that better explains the relationship. This is pretty much what I was looking for. I had no idea the stdin param existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple options here. I usually try to stay away from shelling out to `command` wherever possible. Check out the k8s module in ansible. Note that as long as `state` is `present` ansible will patch your object.

```
- name: Apply your previously generated configmap if you so choose.
  k8s:
    state: present
    definition: "{{ lookup('file', '/output/foo.yml') }}"
```

Or even better, you could just directly create the configmap

```
 - name: Create the configmap for {{ env }}
   k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: ConfigMap
      metadata:
        name: ConfigMap
        namespace: "{{ foo_namespace }}"
        labels:
          app: bar
          environment: "{{ bizzbang }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will look into the k8s module, I believe it will help me